# How to loop entities and modify them

Tags: .net, entity-framework, generics, repository, crud

I don't know if this is possible: is there a way to loop through all the entities of the context of my edmx, get a reference to the entity by find it through its name and update it?

What I thought was that perhaps I can use just one view as a CRUD for many entities that have the same fields (like ID and Name only). So, for example, whenever I want to do an operation with "category1" I can just send its name as a string to the controller, search that entity by its name and update or create a single record in it. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Each entity collection in the context is generically typed.  so unless you know the collection name and correlated Entity Type your approach wouldn't work. -- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx (ObjectContext, CreateObjectSet<T> )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible - look at the `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387138(v=vs.90).aspx

Whether it is sensible is a different question.